# Spotify uploading a playlist image using spotipy python library fails with error 413

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

When I am trying to upload my base64 encoded image I receive a 413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large for url

When clicking the error link that the Spotify API provides in the terminal it says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
(Client Secret,ID and PlaylistID are not real by the way)


import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import base64 #for playlist cover image


playlist_id = "P1a6gzPL0Xg51or8rfirrsr19f6Pi1e4cfzX101fcf"



def change_playlist_cover_image():
    cv = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="7122ce01c646449565965a18c4597779",
                                               client_secret="7f8bcfd7b7e5310bbcc5706b634f4c37",
                                               redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:9090",
                                               scope = "ugc-image-upload"))
    

    image = open('lilmini.jpg', 'rb')
    image_read = image.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)
    cv.playlist_upload_cover_image(playlist_id,image_64_encode)
        

change_playlist_cover_image()
```

I already tried different versions of encoding the image since I thougt I messed up that part.

Also I thought maybe the authorization with SpotifyOAuth is not working properly and tried a few different things there but nothing worked in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add all the required scopes. Also, the image size must be under 256 KB.
Here is the modified code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import base64  # for playlist cover image

playlist_id = "P1a6gzPL0Xg51or8rfirrsr19f6Pi1e4cfzX101fcf"


def change_playlist_cover_image():
    cv = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id="7122ce01c646449565965a18c4597779",
            client_secret="7f8bcfd7b7e5310bbcc5706b634f4c37",
            redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:9090",
            scope="ugc-image-upload playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private",  # added missing scopes
        )
    )

    with open("lilmini.jpg", "rb") as image_file:  # opening file safely
        image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    if len(image_64_encode) > 256000: # check if image is too big
        print("Image is too big: ", len(image_64_encode))
    else:
        cv.playlist_upload_cover_image(playlist_id, image_64_encode)
        print("Image added.")

change_playlist_cover_image()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I copied your code and swapped the playlist ID and client_id/secret but I still get the following  HTTP Error from the spotify API: 

`{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
`
The image I am trying to upload has 51KB

Comment: @iamnotacoder33 You have to to delete the .cache file(s) from the directories you are running the script from. I've had a similar problem before that got solve by that.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt solve the issue, thanks though
I will try to manually send a request to the spotify api and see from there